# Passing checkbox values between asp.net pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, dom-events

On one ASP.NET page, I have a `DataTable` with a list of Investors. The client wanted a feature added that would allow their users to select individual investors from that list and and have an email button that would open up an email page and populate the bcc with the investor emails. So far, I have gotten the checkboxes implemented, and I am successfully going through the checkboxes and grabbing the emails of only the checked boxes. From this point, I am completely lost as to how to send that date over to the next page and have them fill into the bcc automatically.  Here is my code so far:

```
<a onclick="grabEmail()" href="/Settings/EmailSelect" class="button blue" >Email Selected</a> 
...
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function grabEmail() {
    var emails = new Array();
    var $checked = $('[@id=investoremails:checked');
    $checked.each(function () {
        emails.push($(this).val());
        alert($(this).val()); //This was just to check to make sure emails 
                              //were grabbed
    }

    );

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Settings/EmailSelect/',
        type: "POST",
        data: emails,
        traditional: true,

    });
}
```

Then, on EmailSelect page...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Settings/EmailSelect",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $("#results").html("An error occurred: " + error).addClass("notification error");
            return false;
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != null) {
                if (!response.Successful) {
                    $("#results").html("An error occurred: " + response.Exception).addClass("notification error");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $("#bcc").val(response.ReturnVal);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And for the Controller..

```
public ActionResult EmailSelect(string[] emails)
    {
        ViewData["Selected"] = emails;
        return View();
    }
```

We have somewhat similar functionality in this program where Investors can be part of user created groups, and there's another email page where the user can select a specific group to email to, and I was trying to base the solution for this problem off that (even though they are inherently different..). If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Is there a compelling reason that you're doing all of this via `JavaScript`?  I'd be doing virtually all of that work in on the server, rather than on the client.  The button shouldn't be doing anything other than posting back to the server, which, among other things, can perform a redirect.

Comment: What do you think the average, and also the maximum, amount of data you're going to pass is?  If it's going to be sufficiently low I'd stick it in a query string, but if you need to support hundreds of email addresses that's not a practical option.

Comment: There is a senior developer (works out of the office) whom I asked for advice and he suggested "something like that". As far as number of emails, the maximum could be several dozen, so I do not believe a query string would work

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, you're currently sending the data via a query string, it's just in a `post` request of an asynchronous call, so it never ends up in a browser's URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have answered this awhile ago, but I forgot to post it.

I did some research on MVC forms and how they interact with the controller, and I was easily able to get this to work by pulling the checkboxes in as a string array into the controller, and then passing them to the next page in ViewData.